# Access denied for user 'dbtsorder'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

How to solve this message Access denied for user 'dbtsorder'@'localhost' (using password: YES) this message appear only online on localhost work fine
i try to load in file from csv file and this message appear only where this code is

database connection:

```
$host="localhost";
$user="dbtsorder";
$password="M@07765729s";
$db="tsorder";
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES utf8");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8')
```

/*************************************/

Load in file code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
   $link =  realpath('/var/www/order/projectmanagment/'); 
    $checklist = $link.'checklist.csv';     
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select* from tbl_user where db_username='$username'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 $res=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 $fname=$res['db_fname'];
 $lname=$res['db_lname'];
 $name=$res['db_fname'].'&nbsp;'.$res['db_lname'];
    $projectname=$_POST['dep'];
    $location=$_POST['cname'];
    $psd=$_POST['txt_psd'];
    $pdd=$_POST['txt_pdd'];
    $past=$_POST['txt_past'];
    $padd=$_POST['txt_padd'];
    $duration=$_POST['duration'];
    $aduration=$_POST['txt_aduration'];
    $pnote=$_POST['txt_pnote'];
    $transferredto=$_POST['txt_transferredto'];
    $client=$_POST['txt_client'];
    $cpercentage=$_POST['txt_cpercentage'];
    $epercentage=$_POST['txt_epercentage'];
    $mpercentage=$_POST['txt_mpercentage'];
    $sum=$cpercentage+$epercentage+$mpercentage;
    if($projectname=="" || $location=="" || $psd=="" || $pdd=="" || $client=="" ){
        echo"Enter All Information.";
        }
        else{
        if($sum==100){    
            $_SESSION['projectname']=$projectname;
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tbl_project(db_projectname,db_location,db_transferredto,db_psd,db_pdd,db_duration,db_past,db_padd,db_aduration,db_pnote,db_user,db_client,db_cpercentage,db_epercentage,db_mpercentage)VALUES('$projectname','$location','$transferredto','$psd','$pdd','$duration','$past','$padd','$aduration','$pnote','$name','$client','$cpercentage','$epercentage','$mpercentage')")or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$import=mysqli_query($conn,"LOAD DATA INFILE '$checklist' INTO TABLE tbl_checklist FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' set db_projectname='$projectname' ")or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
header("location:allproject.php?msg=2");

}else{echo"Percentage should be equal to 100";}}
        }
```

Comment: Your online database does not have the user `dbtsorder@localhost` with that password, or it does not have access to the tsorder database.

Comment: Can you post your my.cnf i have an idea what the error could be

Comment: production credentials? u need to grant access to `dbtsorder`

Comment: The error message is very self explanatory. You should really try Google first...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried google and i didn't had any solution for that i'm here

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8'` that's unclosed. How do we know whether or not you are using proper closure?

Comment: @Jeredepp i can read and insert and update my database but only in this code the message appear what you mean by the my.cnf and where can i get it

Comment: @Fred-ii- this error is here sorry for that i solve it

Comment: inside your my.cnf you specify the hostname of the DB, if you're using localhost in there it should work, if you got 127.0.0.1 in there your DB will refuse your connection when trying to connect with the hostname (localhost)

Comment: @Jeredepp in the localhost no problem the problem is online only

Comment: For the online version, can you connect to the mysql command line with that username and password? `mysql -u dbtsorder -p tsorder `

Comment: @aynber but this is not my password !!

Comment: @mohamadmohamad: have you consulted the manual? Have you tried what aynber suggests?

Comment: @mohamadmohamad That command prompts you for the password. It's bad practice to put the password in the command, because then it will be in your command history.

Comment: @aynber i changed like you say and i have this message error Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'dbtsorder'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/mhmd2991/public_html/includes/connect.php on line 10
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/mhmd2991/public_html/includes/connect.php on line 11
Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/mhmd2991/public_html/includes/connect.php on line 12

Comment: I did not mean for you to change your code. I meant for you to actually try to connect via the command line, if you have access to a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to read csv file and insert data into database

```
$row=1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r"))!== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
    $num = count($data);       
    $row++;
    if($row>2) 
    {
        if($data[0]!="")
        {
         //write your inset query
        }
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

user this code this will work for you, 
*$data[0]* is the first column, for second use $data[1] etc.

Answer (score 0):

So by looking into my Crystalball the issue seems to be with your Permissions.
In mySql you'll have the choice to whitelist certain clients, i suggest you take a read from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html to understand how your users work

The next step would be to read the following to learn more about the meaning of permissions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html

What's the output of "SHOW GRANTS FOR dbtsorder"

Comment: what should i do exactly ?!

Answer (score 0):

Error is clearly showing that there is a connection problem, please check wheather ***dbtsorder*** user has access of ***tsorder*** or not. If not then first give this user access to particular database.

Comment: if is a connection problem why other page don't have the same message and why i can read and insert and update and delete from the database only in the page where i use load in file i have this problem is there any other code can i read from a csv file and insert into database ?

Comment: please find the csv reader code in my next next answer @mohamadmohamad